# wget resolves to a different IP than host

Tags: shell, ubuntu, wget, host

I have a shell script in which I use `host` to get the IP of the target site to update `ufw` and allow outbound traffic to that IP. However, when I make the subsequent `wget` call to the same base URL, it resolves to a different IP, and thus is blocked by `ufw`. Just to test, I tried pinging the URL, and it returned a different third IP.

We're blocking all outbound traffic by default in `ufw`, and only enable what we need to go out, so I need the script to update the correct IP so I can `wget` the content. The IP in each instance (`host` vs `wget`) is consistently the same, but they return different values with respect to each other, so I don't think it's simply a DNS issue. How do I get a consistent IP to update the firewall with, so that the subsequent `wget` request performs successfully? I disabled the firewall as a test, and was able to download from the URL successfully, so the issue is definitely in getting a consistent IP to point to.

```
HOSTNAME=<name of site to resolve>
LOGFILE=<logfile path>
Current_IP=$(host $HOSTNAME | head -n 1 | cut -d " " -f 4)

#this echoes the correct value
echo $Current_IP

if [ ! -f $LOGFILE ]; then
    /usr/sbin/ufw allow out from any to $Current_IP
    echo $Current_IP > $LOGFILE
    echo New IP address found and logged >> ./download.log
else

    Old_IP=$(cat $LOGFILE)
    if [ "$Current_IP" = "$Old_IP" ] ; then
        echo IP address has not changed >> ./download.log
    else
        /usr/sbin/ufw delete allow out from any to $Old_IP
        /usr/sbin/ufw allow out from any to $Current_IP
        echo $Current_IP > $LOGFILE
        echo IP Address was updated in ufw >> ./download.log
    fi
fi
```

After that updates the firewall, a subsequent `wget` to `HOSTNAME` attempts to go out to a different IP than was just updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the difference was "www.". When I was resolving `host` I was not using www, and when I was using `wget` I was using www, and thus they resolved to different IPs for this particular site.

Comment: FYI -- `getent hosts hostname` is better than `host hostname` for simulating what the libc resolver would do. The `host` command doesn't know about `/etc/hosts`, or `nsswitch`, or many other configurations that can change how name resolution takes place. (And in general, `dig +short` is the modern replacement for `host`, though it too has the limitations mentioned above).

Comment: Thanks! That's good to know for future use.

Comment: You pointed out the obvious: host vs. getent. I have managed Yellow pages in the past, and still wasn't aware of the getent command. Thanks for that, Charles!